# Why does [FromBody] ignore model binders?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, frombodyattribute

I'm working on an REST API in ASP.NET. One of the first things I made was a Model Binder for the model, binded with the model by a code like this:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelModelBinder))]
public class MyModel { ... }
```

And used it in an action

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(MyModel model) { ... }
```

I realised, quite suddenly, that after I added the [FromBody] before the parameter type...

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]MyModel model) { ... }
```

...the Model Binder gets ignored. I tried to debug it by puting a breakpoint on the beginning of the BindModel method and at the beginning of the action and realised that when I call the action I get straight to the action. When I delete the FromBody Attribute the breakpoint in the ModelBinder becomes active again.

Why can't I use both? Why is the FromBody attribute ignoring the ModelBinder?

Comment: I don't think you can use both a FromBody (which is base on `HttpParameterBinding`) and a ModelBinder. According to [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api]) you can override the default policy by implementing an `IActionValueBinder `

Comment: I guess this is the article that @Michael mentioned https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api